# d3.ticks() in d3 v4 often gives a top tick value lower than the highest value in the range

Tags: d3.js

[In D3 version 4's D3-array module](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#ticks), `d3.ticks()` takes an array and outputs an array of nicely-rounded values suitable for chart axis labels:

> **`d3.ticks(start, stop, count)`**
>
> Returns an array of approximately count + 1 uniformly-spaced, nicely-rounded values between start and stop (inclusive). Each value is a power of ten multiplied by 1, 2 or 5. See also [tickStep](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#tickStep) and [linear.ticks](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#linear_ticks)...
>
> Ticks are inclusive in the sense that they may include the specified start and stop values if (and only if) they are exact, nicely-rounded values consistent with the inferred step. More formally, each returned tick t satisfies start ≤ t and t ≤ stop.

However, I don't get the results I expect. For example, for this:

```
  d3.ticks( 0, 63500, 7 );
```

I'd expect output like:

```
  [ 0, 10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000 ]
```

Instead, what I get is:

```
  [ 0, 10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000 ]
```

... where my highest value (63500) is greater than my chart's highest tick, meaning I'd expect a value to extend off the chart.

Requesting a different number of ticks doesn't solve it:

- `( 0, 63500, 8 )` gives the same thing
- `( 0, 63500, 9 )` also gives the same
- `( 0, 63500, 10 )` gives `[0, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 30000, 35000, 40000, 45000, 50000, 55000, 60000]` which is no better
- From random trial and error, the only input I could find that actually exceeded my maximum value was `24`, which gave `[0, 2000, 4000, ... 62000, 64000]`
- This is for a function that can be passed any data set, so it can't require a hand-picked number of ticks for each data set

Why is this happening (have I misunderstood something, or doesn't this violate "t ≤ stop") from the docs?), and how do I ensure that my ticks do cover my range?

---

I've seen the question [d3.js scale doesn't place tick at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138911/d3-js-scale-doesnt-place-tick-at-the-top) which describes a similar problem in D3 version 3 with an illustration:

[image]

...but the functions are different in version 4 and the documentation links in the answer don't apply to D3 version 4.

I've looked at [D3-Scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#linear_ticks) - the link to `linear.ticks()` appears to be broken - but I'm not really understanding why what I'm trying to do would need a whole new D3 submodule and scaling algorithim.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
getRoundedYMaxValue(number) {
        var numLen = number.toString().length;
        var dividerValue = "1"
        for (var i = 0; i < numLen - 1; i++) {
            dividerValue += 0
        }
        return Math.ceil(number / dividerValue) * dividerValue
    }
```